# How to update "unsupported version of OpenGL" for Dying Light on Steam?

Tags: drivers, graphics, steam, opengl

I just bought and downloaded Dying Light. When trying to start the game it gives me:

Unsupported version of OpenGL!:
Detected OpenGL version: 3.0 Mesa 18.2.2
Required OpenGL version: 3.3
Please update your display driver.

I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. 
Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
I was hoping someone has solved this issue with Dying Light.

Comment: Are you using open source graphic card driver or proprietary? You can check it in Applications -> type in search field "**Software & Updates**" -> tab **Additional Drivers**..

Comment: I think we should start by asserting which graphics card you have. Please [edit] and post the hardware specifications. Then we'll try to find out if it supports newer OpenGL. There's a change it might not. If it's an integrate Intel Graphics then probably not and it's already using the correct driver. @S_Flash comment above makes sense only if the card is Nvidia and is not running with the Nvida proprietary drivers.

Comment: Additionally, Dying Light requires **NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 560 / AMD Radeon™ HD 6870 (1GB VRAM)** as minimum. No mention of Intel Graphics means it won't run. **Always check the system requirements for any software**.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using the command

```
nvidia-settings
```

It opens a graphical interface to manage settings of your graphical card. In my case, my computer was using Intel graphics by default (to save power) and was not able to lauch dying light. After the modification (using sudo) it was working.